# How to manipulate/remove the sub-documents in MongoDB through MongooseJS?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
//define suberSchema
var suberSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    constraints: [constraintSchema]
});

//define spaceInfoSchema
var spaceInfoSchema = new Schema({
    spaceName: String,
    subers: [suberSchema],
    _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
   }
});
```

I want to manipulate/get the subdocs but when I use the following code, it just operates the parentdocs.

- This returns an array with all subers. What should I do to get the suber with the specified id?

`spaceInfoModel.find({"_id": spaceId,"subers._id": userId}, "subers", callback);`

- This removes the whole document. What should I do to remove the suber with the specified id?

`spaceInfoModel.remove({"_id": spaceId,"subers._id": userId}, callback);`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` will always return documents from the collection it is called on. In your example that would be `spaceInfoModel`. The query: `spaceInfoModel.find({"_id": spaceId,"subers._id": userId}, "subers", callback);` is checking for a document in `spaceInfoModel`'s collection that matches the id of `spaceId` and also has a sub-doc with an id of `userId`. If any matching documents are found they would be returned as an array to the callback function.

At this point you can use the helper function [`id()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray.id) to retrieve the sub-doc:

```
// Using findOne but you could easily match this with findById as well
spaceInfoModel.findOne({"_id": spaceId,"subers._id": userId}, 'subers').exec().then(function(spaceInfo) {
  // spaceInfo.subers is the entire sub-doc array
  return spaceInfo.subers.id(userId);
}).then(function(suber) {
  // do something with the suber
}).then(null, function(err) { ... });
```

This however has the unfortunate side effect of returning all sub-docs just so you can prune it down to one. A more efficient way would be to have Mongo pare down the sub-doc array before returning the parent doc. The [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator can be used to do this.

```
spaceInfoModel.findById(spaceId).select({subers: {$elemMatch: {_id: userId}}}).exec().then(function(spaceInfo) {
  // spaceInfo.subers is an array of only the matching sub-doc
  return spaceInfo.subers.id(userId);
}).then(function(suber) {
  // do something with the suber
}).then(null, function(err) { ... });
```

Going beyond this you could also explore using an aggregate pipeline to unwind the document sub-docs but I don't believe there would be much to gain over using `elemMatch()`.

To remove a sub-doc can be done in a similar manner. The first approach requires retrieving the entire array down and then modifying it locally with [`pull()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.pull) before saving it back to MonogoDB.

```
spaceInfoModel.findOne({"_id": spaceId,"subers._id": userId}, 'subers').exec().then(function(spaceInfo) {
  // spaceInfo.subers is the entire sub-doc array
  // remove the matching ID
  spaceInfo.subers.pull({_id: userId});

  // Commit to mongoDB
  return spaceInfo.save();
}).then(function() {
  ...
}).then(null, function(err) { ... });
```

Again, this could be done more efficiently directly on the MongoDB server.

```
spaceInfoModel.findByIdAndUpdate(spaceId, {$pull: {subers: {_id: userId}}}).select({subers: {$elemMatch: {_id: userId}}}).exec().then(function(spaceInfo) {
  // spaceInfo.subers is an array of only the matching sub-doc
  // the original doc is returned with the removed sub-doc on success
  return spaceInfo.subers.id(userId);
}).then(function(suber) {
  // do something with the suber
}).then(null, function(err) { ... });
```

**NOTE:** `$elemMatch` is only used to return the sub-doc that was removed. If you don't care about that you could simplify it to:

```
spaceInfoModel.findByIdAndUpdate(spaceId, {$pull: {subers: {_id: userId}}}).exec().then(function(spaceInfo) {
  ...
}).then(null, function(err) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience and professional reply.It's really helpful.By the way,it's my first time to ask questions here and your reply inspired me to fall in love with this place.

Comment: @biteme Glad to help and welcome! Don't forget to accept an answer if your question was answered so other SO users will know. :)

Comment: @biteme Hmmmmm, it looks like the mongooseJS `elemMatch` maps to the select and not the projection operator. I made an update. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @biteme Apologies, that was a mistake on my part. That's interesting. It returns the entire `subers` array rather than a one item array?

Comment: @biteme Okay, my apologies again. I took a second and looked at it a bit closer. This update should map mongo's functionality to mongoose's API.

Comment: Thanks again and it solved my problems finally.I think the mongoose API document is just a mess.I tried to up this answer but failed because of the lack of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this

```
spaceInfoModel.aggregate({$match
{
    "_id": spaceId,
}},{$unwind:'$subers"}, {$match:{
    "subers._id": userId
}}, "subers", callback);
```

You get result like this

```
[{_id: '****',subers: {_id: '',constraints: [some data]}}]
```

For remove

```
spaceInfoModel.update(
{
    "_id": spaceId,
      "subers._id": userId
},{$pull:{subers:{_id:userId}}},callback)
```

Comment: Thanks.But is there an easier way to just get the `{_id: '',constraints: [some data]} `and what should I do when I remove the sub documents?

Comment: You have to do  spaceInfoModel.update({"_id": spaceId,"subers._id": userId},{$pull:{subers:{_id:userId}}})

Comment: there are some errors when I use the aggregate function.It seems the syntax can't be recognized by mongoose. I'm trying to fix it,and I would let you know if necessary.